# Ordered and Sorted ggplot Bar Graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a bar graph of an interaction between 'Treatment' and 'Day' from my data set. I want 'Treatment' to be sorted in the following order: 'Before', 'During', and 'After' and I would also like 'Day' 1 and 2 'Before', 'During', and 'After' next to each other, rather than having each 'Day' grouped together. Here is my data set:

```
structure(list(Name = structure(c(9L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 
15L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 11L, 16L, 16L, 13L, 
13L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 
14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 11L, 
16L, 16L, 13L, 13L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 
9L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 
2L, 2L, 11L, 11L, 16L, 16L, 13L, 13L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("DSGW", "DSOR", "DSYB", "GSWP", 
"LSGL", "LSLL", "OSLL", "PSYP", "PSYR", "RSBB", "RSBP", "RSYY", 
"WSGG", "WSPB", "WSRR", "WSRW"), class = "factor"), Day = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), 
Treatment = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("After", 
"Before", "During"), class = "factor"), Behavior = c(3040L, 
3219L, 2378L, 3529L, 3135L, 3702L, 2868L, 3035L, 1614L, 833L, 
1255L, 1224L, 1569L, 1433L, 1567L, 1448L, 1197L, 1619L, 1543L, 
1309L, 1738L, 1378L, 1362L, 1603L, 1109L, 1073L, 570L, 822L, 
815L, 1166L, 0L, 835L, 3060L, 2815L, 2875L, 3394L, 3009L, 
3274L, 2350L, 2455L, 972L, 815L, 983L, 1033L, 1520L, 1477L, 
1461L, 1395L, 1242L, 1368L, 1637L, 1275L, 1646L, 1546L, 1064L, 
971L, 596L, 1461L, 1276L, 1272L, 872L, 1026L, 1249L, 592L, 
2277L, 3022L, 2997L, 3495L, 2591L, 3447L, 2479L, 2701L, 175L, 
452L, 1287L, 1355L, 1252L, 1501L, 1371L, 1147L, 1465L, 1003L, 
1510L, 0L, 1744L, 1026L, 959L, 898L, 1529L, 1092L, 417L, 
289L, 40L, 762L, 1495L, 896L)), .Names = c("Name", "Day", 
"Treatment", "Behavior"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-96L))
```

Here is the script I am using to produce my current figure:

```
   ggplot(perch1, aes(x = interaction(Treatment,Day), y = Behavior, fill =  factor(Day)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to use facet wrap to plot each treatment in a separate panel.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Day), y = Behavior, fill = factor(Day))) + 
       geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + facet_wrap(~Treatment, nrow = 1)
```

This won't label your interaction on the X-axis, but instead puts it in the panel title.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide an alternative solution. I think this way is a bit cleaner; however, I'm sure there are ways to clean up the x-axis with the first answer, I'm just not overly skilled with ggplot. I will say that this solution doesn't inherently sort the Treatments like I needed, so I added the following script to accomplish that:     

    


    df$Treatment<- factor(df$Treatment, levels =c("Before","During","After"))

Answer (score 1):

One option is to just add a new column to your `data.frame` and manually specify the order of the levels, rather than messing around with `interaction`:

```
library(ggplot2)
##
df$Group <- factor(
  paste0(df$Day," : ",df$Treatment),
  paste0(rep(1:2,3)," : ",
         rep(c("Before","During","After"),each=2)))
##
R> ggplot(
    df, 
    aes(x=Group, 
        y=Behavior, 
        fill=factor(Day)))+
    geom_bar(stat='identity')+
    scale_x_discrete(
      labels=paste0("Day ",levels(df$Group)))
```

[image]

Comment: For starters, your answer seems to have sorted things like I need just fine, so thank you. However, I'm not convinced that this is the best way to go about it since it creates a really messy x-axis (although, I'm not an expert, so I apologize if this IS actually the best way). If you could help with a follow up, I would appreciate it. How can I label groups of two bars with 'Before', 'During', and 'After'? I would think using scale_x_discrete, but I can't quite figure it out without altering your answer?